# How to use Node.js at the back-end in front-end scala play framework application?

Tags: node.js, scala, playframework

I build a web application using scala play framework but now I want to add features like Authentication, storing data in the database(MongoDB) using Post request with the help of Node.js. How do I connect both of them to work? Scala uses pages like `home.scala.html` for rendering pages. How do I connect it with node.js?

Comment: You mean post request from your home.scala.html to Node server?